# Relay current question

Tags: current, relay

For the [16 CH 12V Relay module](http://www.sainsmart.com/16-channel-12v-relay-module-for-pic-arm-avr-dsp-arduino-msp430-ttl-logic.html), does the output currency mean that we could run 5VDC, 12VDC or 24VDC through the relay? What ever current we input will be the output current, correct?

Comment: You still haven't replied to our question on [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35809/8-channel-5v-relay) of yours. And I told you I won't answer any more of your questions until you accept a few answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, the relays installed on the module are rated at 30VDC, 10A; so you can use it to drive anything below that range (that means 5VDC, 12VDC, 24VDC are ok. Make sure the current are below 10A though).

2) Yes, relay works like a physical switch; once connected, the current flows. The rated contact resistance of the relay is [100mOhm](http://docs-asia.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/0b76/0900766b80b76b3c.pdf).

Comment: Loss in a relay is definitely *not* negligible. At 100 m\$\Omega\$ contact resistance and a current of 10 A dissipation in the contact will be 10 W!

Comment: @stevenvh you are right. Just found out that the rated max contact resistance the relay is 100mOhm. I got used to ignore it because the load i connect my relay normally have much higher resistance compare to the relay. thanks.